# On-board motherboard graphics no longer working after installing graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, blank-screen

I recently purchased an ASUS GTX 1050 and installed it. When plugged into the graphics card I get a blank screen, which is to be expected, as I have yet to install my drivers. To install my drivers I thought "I'll just plug into the on board graphics in my motherboard" this, however did not go as planned. The on board graphics also result in a black screen, it should also be mentioned that this black screen is not only present when in the operating system (Ubuntu 16.04), but the BIOS screen is also blank. I will admit that up to this point I have never used the on board graphics, as my old graphics card needed no drivers installed, but I don't see why they would not work. While my PC is on, every fan and light indicates that it is working correctly, as does the motherboard speaker. I've already checked, and it is neither a cord or monitor problem, so I don't understand why I can't use the on board graphics while I install the drivers.

In summary: My graphics card gets a black screen, which is normal, but so does my integrated on board graphics, which is not normal. As of right now I just want to get my on board graphics working so that I can install drivers, or so that my PC is at least functional.

Update: after removing the graphics card, the on board graphics are working now. I no longer have a problem as I will  install the drivers and put it back in.

Comment: Having a black screen from your graphics card is not normal, you should have a display even without drivers installed but it might just be at a low resolution.  You will also not be able to use 3D graphics until you install drivers but you *should* have a display from the card.

Comment: To my understanding, Windows comes with basic drivers witch allow it to work while you install the new ones, this however is not the case for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Many computers have a setting in the Bios that controls the on-board video while another gfx-card is present.
Typically the on-board automatically goes completely OFF, is forced ON or there is some Auto-switch functionally (mostly found on laptops).
That Auto-switch setting often gives trouble. How that works out can depend on the exact card, even exact video-bios of the Gfx-card. (I have seen if stop working after a video-card bios-upgrade while it was fine with the old bios.) That may also explain why things worked with the old card, but not with the new one.

Remedy in most cases is getting into the Bios (removing the gfx-card if needed to get at the bios) and force the on-board graphics setting to either "always on" or  "Always off". One of them should fix your issues.
Sometimes a Bios update on the motherboard works wonders too.